# Adding fields into interface

Tags: typescript, interface

## Description and code examples

I'm building a project on **vanilla JS** using **TS**.

I have a custom storage class which is stored in window object so I can interact with it wherever:

**CustomStorage.ts**

```js
class CustomStorage {
    private static _core: Record<string, any> = {};
    private _core: Record<string, any>;

    constructor() {
        if (!CustomStorage._core)
            CustomStorage._core = {};

        this._core = CustomStorage._core;
        (window as any).CustomStorage = this;
    }

    get items(): Record<string, any> {
        return this._core;
    }

    setItem(prop: string, value: any): void {
        this._core[prop] = value;
    }

    clearStorage(): void {
        this._core = {};
    }
}

export default CustomStorage;
```

I use this storage in many files throughout the project, and I want to know which fields my storage has in any external file

For example I have a separate file where I fill my storage to use this data later:

**(Not full file):**

```js
export default function fillStorage() {
    /**
     * TableHeaders - needed for the table to print only exact columns
     * Also stores into the Storage to be able to be called later
    */
    const tableHeaders: string[] = ['ProdCode', 'Customer', 'ProdName', 'HostName', 'MatNum', 'ArticleNum', 'WkStNmae', 'AdpNum', 'ProcName', 'AVO', 'FPY', 'CountPass', 'CountFail', 'tLogIn', 'tLogOut', 'tLastAcc'];
    Storage.setItem('tableHeaders', tableHeaders);

    Storage.setItem('selectedHeaders', []);

    if (Storage.items.data) {
        // StaticData - stored to be a full version of initial array
        Storage.setItem('staticData', Storage.items.data);

        // AllHeaders - needs for reset listener to fill dropdown immediately
        Storage.setItem('allHeaders', Object.keys(Storage.items.staticData[0]));

        // StaticDataLength - stored, not to calculate length later
        Storage.setItem('staticDataLength', Storage.items.staticData.length);
        Storage.setItem('headers', Object.keys(Storage.items.data[0]));

        // AllValues - as same as allHeaders. not to calculate later. Receives all present value from the static data
        Storage.setItem('allValues', DropdownValues(Storage.items.staticData, Storage.items.tableHeaders));

        // Stored not to keep text present as it takes lot of memory
        Storage.setItem('inputTextLength', Storage.items.data.length);
    }
```

And when I want to use this data later in a file like

**index.ts:**

```js
const handleFiltersEraserClick = async (e: MouseEvent) => {
    const target = e.target as HTMLElement;

    if (target?.id.substring(0, 6) === 'eraser') {
        const targetId: string = target?.id.slice(7);

        Storage.items.inputFields[+targetId - 1].value = '';
        Storage.items.dbSelects[+targetId - 1].selectedIndex = 0;

        Storage.items.dataSourceOption === 'Datenbank'
            ? await DBQuery()
            : Storage.setItem('data', getFilters() as object[]);
        if (rowsAmount) {
            Storage.items.data.length === 0
                ? rowsAmount.innerHTML = '0'
                : rowsAmount.innerHTML = Storage.items.data.length;
        }

        let dropdownValues: { values: string[], valueToHeaderMap: object } | null = DropdownValues(Storage.items.data, Storage.items.tableHeaders);

        Storage.items.datalists.forEach((datalist: HTMLDataListElement) => {
            datalist.innerHTML = '';

            dropdownValues?.values.forEach((value: string) => {
                const option: HTMLOptionElement = document.createElement('option');
                option.className = 'datalist-option';
                option.value = value;
                datalist.appendChild(option);
            });
        });

        dropdownValues = null;
    }
};
```

I shall guess if I chose right field or not. That's why I want to have an `interface` (probably) to know all the time what fields I have.

I could just create a static interface, but I have many cases when new fields are being added to the storage after **fillStorage()** call

## Question:

Is it possible to extend initial interface when something is being added into storage? Making static `interface` could lead to issues when I have such field in the interface, but it will be `undefined` cause it still doesn't exist

## How I see it

I have initial interface

```js
interface Storage {
   staticData: object[],
   allHeaders: string[],
   staticDataLength: number,
   headers: string[],
   allValues: object[],
   inputTextLength: number
}
```

after something happened and I added f.e.

`Storage.setItem('numbers', [1, 2, 3])`

I need then this `number` to appear in `interface Storage` so I will have

```js
interface Storage {
   staticData: object[],
   allHeaders: string[],
   staticDataLength: number,
   headers: string[],
   allValues: object[],
   inputTextLength: number,
   numbers: number[]
}
```

And if I delete field from `Storage` to delete corresponding field from the `interface`

---

Hope I've been clear in my question. Any recommendations and advices would be highly appreciated

Comment: Types in TS don’t have *state*.  You can’t add and remove fields from them during the control flow of your program. Neither can TS track arbitrary state changes of values.  I could *almost* imagine writing something that would keep track of *adding* fields (although the compiler wouldn’t know *when* the fields were added), but *deleting* fields seems impossible.  I don’t know if anyone else has a clever alternative.

Comment: your answer tells me a lot, but maybe someone can suggest any other possible way or idea. will wait

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking in the wrong places, and I recommend you look at the compiled JavaScript output from TypeScript.  Interfaces do not emit any code at all, they are only there to describe objects within TypeScript.  That's the "type" in TypeScript!

A few tips about types:

- avoid using `object` for a type, that is far too generic. Better describe your objects instead.
- avoid using the `any` type - since it can be anything why bother using TypeScript at all? It's best to describe your objects instead.
- prefix interfaces & type names with `I` so it's easier to tell what is an interface and what is not
- You can add optional properties with a `?` suffix on the property name
- Types cannot be modified at runtime because they are not code, you can however extend types

Here's a demo rewrite of your type with some made up interfaces to use instead of `object`. Note the optional properties

```ts
interface IData {
  foo: string;
  bar?: number;
}

interface IValue {
  baz: string;
  val?: number;
}

interface IStorage {
   staticData: IData[],
   allHeaders: string[],
   staticDataLength: number,
   headers: string[],
   allValues: IValue[],
   inputTextLength: number
}

interface IStorageWithNumbers extends IStorage {
   numbers: number[]
}

const myStorage: IStorageWithNumbers = {
  staticData: [{foo: 'a'}, {foo: 'b', bar: 2}],
  allHeaders: [''],
  staticDataLength: 0,
  headers: [''],
  allValues: [{baz: 'c', val: 3}, {baz: 'd'}],
  inputTextLength: 0,
  numbers: [1, 2, 3]
};
```

Please check this [TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIBE5jsg3gKGWRgHsSAuZAZzClAHMBuQ5AIzigH5KQBXAW1bRmAX3z5QkWIhSoAanAA2vFASLsAXpRp0QTFgDcl3ZH0HD8YieGjwkaAMpgSUOPVUtq2MMASZslBhYcADaALoANJ5KigASEHAAJtBU2rQM4VFEXli+-nAAMhB6YAAWPAJCUFlEpQnJUKleuvSZ0YqKCsoQTfJKKm3ZoAAOvGAAKhAAHmBFJeWmldCW4pK2Mo7Oru4A6sBlAHJLjcjTkCCJVJsubh7ZZlVND9DhK-gIJCA0yPwAnk43dyBAHbCB7Q7HK4AXjwLBouT8wUoIVwpAoyAA5HAMSIIng0ZQMawMXj2FBKAAmESRFgxeJJFLIjEYmlEeE+RHYOb0MqUAAMNTqDMaTJZNRiXRUTRRmkJCBJyCMikoAGZcXhZZjEjjWcgRmNJjNubzkAKWM8RcgQgBGPEUvEqsKWRhAA) and see the JS output from it by selecting ".JS" on the right side

Comment: 2. `any`s here in my code are consequences of my first code when I migrated project on ts (it was js first). 4. I actually had a thought about optional properties. Thanks for an explanation